# build Coded UI tests in TFS 2017 + vsTest + error

Tags: build-process, coded-ui-tests

I have `codedUI` and unit tests in my solution. Solution and the unit tests are successfully building in TFS 2017. `CodedUI` tests fail. I get an error.

> Failed to initialize the unit test extension 'urn:CodedUITest': A unit test extension is not registered for the following attribute: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute.

All the tests successfully pass in my local machine. What configuration am I missing in my build process?

kindly, help!.

Comment: Did you install the Coded UI features on your build server?

Comment: Do you have the Visual Studio installed on the build agent? Are you using Visual Studio Test Platform Installer? What's the result if you manually run Code UI in the build agent machine?

Comment: @DanielMann yes.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT : VS is installed in build server. i'm using just VS installer. UI tests successfully run manually on the server.

Comment: @AnjaliIyengar To run Coded UI test, you have to configure the **test agent to interact with the Desktop** and build agent running as interactive Mode. Please make sure you have enable it in Agent Configuration of Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error info, seems the issue should more related to build agent Environment setting. Make sure you **have Visual Studio and Coded UI features installed on the build agent**. You could double check this by remote to the build agent and manually run Code UI in the agent machine instead of through TFS build.

If you are using Nuget Visual Studio Test Platform Installer , this is not support for now, take a look at the similar issue: [VSTS build release agent unable to run Coded UI tests when using the Nuget VsTest platform](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1353)

> Currently Coded UI and UWP tests not support with VSTest platform
>   nuget package. /cc @PBoraMSFT for blog/doc and timeline for support.